# Why do I get an error when I try to use the format simplification of anonymous functions

Tags: scala, lambda, anonymous-function

In scala, if a parameter only appears once, can it be replaced by _, but why not here.

i want to know why this way of coding is wrong,and what is the underlying principle?

```scala
object Spark01_RDD_Operator_Transform_glom {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("RDD")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val rdd = sc.makeRDD(List(1, 2, 3, 4), 2)

    val glomMap = rdd.glom().map(
      array => {
        array.max
      }
    )

    println(rdd.glom().collect().foreach(_ => println(_.mkString(","))))

    println(glomMap.collect().mkString(","))

    println(glomMap.collect().sum)

    sc.stop()

  }

}
```

Comment: `_ => println(_.mkString(","))` is `(x: Array[Array[Int]]) => println((y: ???) => y.mkString(","))`. So you should write `x => println(x.mkString(","))`.

Comment: or `_.mkString(",") andThen println _`

Comment: Really, just stay away of the `_` syntax, especially when learning, it only works for the most simplest of cases.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Not so FP point-free style? :)

Comment: @DmytroMitin so just for clarifying something I didn't say in the original comment, both that one and this are just personal opinions _(i.e. extremely subjective)_. But yeah, I would advise not focusing on point-free style FP in **Scala**, especially while learning. Dot notation and explicit lambdas work great all the time, and they are not too boilerplate most of the time.